# pyTelegramBotAPI действие над сообщением, на которое ответили

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Например, бот прислал сообщение, я отвечаю на него какой-нибудь командой, после чего над выбранным сообщением совершается действие, например пишу "сохранить", после чего сообщение сохраняется в текстовик. Либо без команды, просто выполняется действие.

[image: Пример]

Интересует способ доставания текста сообщения, на которое отвечаешь.

**main.py**:

```
import telebot
from telebot.types import Message

import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

bot.send_message(config.owner_id, 'Привет')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

**config.py**:

```
token = 'token'
owner_id = 123456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if hasattr(message.reply_to_message, 'text'):
    print('сообщение: ' + message.reply_to_message.text, 'ответ: ' + message.text)
else:
    print('без ответа')
```

либо

```
# noinspection PyBroadException
    try:
        print('сообщение: ' + message.reply_to_message.text, 'ответ: ' + message.text)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

*D. Violet*, спасибо!

А вот пример использования:

```
import telebot
from telebot.types import Message

import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text(message: Message):
    try:
        if hasattr(message.reply_to_message, 'text'):
            msg = message.reply_to_message.text
            hi = msg.split('\n')
            if message.text == 'Сохрани телефон':
                number = hi[3]
                number = number[9:]
                print(number)
                with open('number.txt', 'w') as file:
                    file.write(number)

                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Готово!')
            elif message.text == 'Сохрани заявку':
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ещё не завезли :С')
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Такой команды нет!')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Имя: Артём\n'
                                              'Фамилия: Некрасов\n'
                                              'Пол: М\n'
                                              'Телефон: 88005553535')
    except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```